# Representing a dictionary<string, string> in .NET Core environment variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a configuration section in my web app for different MIME types represented as a JSON dictionary like so:

```
"AllowedMimeTypes": {
    "image/*": "",
    "application/pdf": "pdf",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "excel",
    "application/vnd.ms-excel": "excel",
    "application/msword": "word",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": "word"
}
```

This is the class it maps to:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp.Models.Config
{
    public class AllowedMimeTypes : Dictionary<string, string>
    {
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when I run it locally using secrets.json, but when I host it in Azure I have to represent it as environment variables and I cannot seem to find anything that works.

I've tried "AllowedMimeTypes:0:Key" with "AllowedMimeTypes:0:Value" and "AllowedMimeTypes:0:image/*" which both throw an exception and "AllowedMimeTypes:0" which doesn't but doesn't give me the correct configuration values.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Right now there's nothing that we can get working until we see the code and see the issue you're facing.

Comment: See this topic https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/469

Comment: I've edited my original question to add the class that inherits from Dictionary<string, string> but I'm not sure what else you need to see.  I'm trying to inject it via IOptionsSnapshot<AllowedMimeTypes> but I don't know what format the environment variables need to be in for this to work.

Comment: You'd need something like: `AllowedMimeTypes:application/pdf`, but I'm not even sure if that will work because of the slash.

Comment: @ChrisPratt you are a genius!  That was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can represent your dictionary key/value pairs as environment variables by placing the key as the last segment of the env var name, and the value of the env var set to the value you want in the dictionary, e.g `AllowedMimeTypes:application/pdf=pdf` or `AllowedMimeTypes__application/pdf=pdf`.

Note that if you're working with a shell you could have some trouble creating these environment variables (primarily `AllowedMimeTypes__image/*`), but it should be a restriction imposed by the shell not the operating system.

For completeness:

```
AllowedMimeTypes__image/*=
AllowedMimeTypes__application/pdf=pdf
AllowedMimeTypes__application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=excel
AllowedMimeTypes__application/vnd.ms-excel=excel
AllowedMimeTypes__application/msword=word
AllowedMimeTypes__application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=word
```

P.S.

Using something like `AllowedMimeTypes:0:Key` and `AllowedMimeTypes:0:Value` would work if you were using an *array* of objects that contained strings for `Key` and `Value`.  E.g.

```
public class KVPair {
    public string Key, Value;
}

public class AllowedMimeTypes : List<KVPair> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not automatically converted to a configuration object but you can store your dictionary as an environment variable in JSON format such as

```
AllowedMimeTypes="[{'image/*': '', 'application/pdf': 'pdf', 'application/msword': 'word'}]"
```

and than you can convert it to a dictionary manually

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```